# How to get last inserted id using Eloquent::insert()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am inserting bulk insertions in laravel 5 like this:

```
$data = array(
    array('name'=>'Jack', 'age'=>'24'),
    array('name'=>'Tom', 'age'=>'37'),
    //...
);

Users::insert($data);
```

Any idea how to get last inserted id?

Comment: The easiest way ...  

    $data = array(
        array('name'=>'Jack', 'age'=>'24'),
        array('name'=>'Tom', 'age'=>'37'),
        //...
    );

    foreach($data as $user){
        $u = Users::create($user);
        $u->save();
        $lastId = $u->id;
    }

    echo $lastId;

Comment: Just to clarify, are you wanting the very last inserted id or all the ids for the inserted data?

Answer (score 0):

So, you can't use `insertGetId()` when bulk inserting data. So if you want to keep DB integrity, you could do something like this:

```
$lastRow = array_pop($data); // Cutting off last item from an array

Users::insert($data);
$lastId = Users::insertGetId($lastRow);
```

I know this is pretty dumb solution and it will create 2 queries instead of one, but if you'll not find anything better, you could use it.

**Alternative**

You could also try this:

```
$lastId = DB::select('select last_insert_id()');
```

This could work and [it shouldn't brake DB integrity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html):

> For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and
>   not 0).

Answer (score -1):

You can both way

**Using Eloquent Model**

```
$user = new Reports();        
$user->email= 'johndoe@example.com';  
$user->save();
$lastInsertId = $user->id;
```

**Or**

**Using Query Builder**

```
 $lastInsertId = DB::table('reports')->insertGetId(['email' => 'johndoe@example.com']);
```

Comment: The op has specifically asked for an example using mass insertion `insert()`